# bash eval equation right value can not include space

Tags: bash, eval

In bash shell script, I want to create series of variables and assign string values to them

```
a=aaa

eval $a="a b c"
```

turns out :

```
b not found...
```

Why the right value cannot contain space?

Comment: Warning: `eval` makes the shell parsing process even messier and harder to understand than it usually is. This problem is one example, but there are lots more ways to run into trouble with it. I recommend avoiding it whenever possible (see glenn jackman's answer for one option).

Answer (score 1):

It's because `eval $a="a b c"` is expanded to `aaa=a b c`

Solutions:

```
eval "$a=\"a b  c\""

# or better
printf "-v$a" "a b c"
```

Comment: Ah, a real master you are. Perfectly solved my confusing and problem.  Good night to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach for `declare` when you want to use eval for variable assignment.

```
$ declare "$a=a b c"
$ echo $aaa
a b c
```

Comment: This is better.